# How do I remove interior brackets from a range of superscript citations?

Tags: bibtex, citing, ieeetran, brackets, superscripts

I'm using the `cite` package as follows

```
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}
```

However, when I try to cite multiple articles, the range includes interior brackets, as seen  here.[image]

Can anyone tell me how to remove these so the superscript only contains `6--8`? I'm using the `IEEEtran conference` document class and the `IEEEtran bibliographystyle` if that has anything to do with it.

Thanks!

### Edit

Per request, I'm including a working example of the file.

```
\documentclass[11pt,conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Several tools rely on this identification of discordant read pairs to detect SV~\cite{alkan2011sv,rausch2012delly,Layer2014lumpy}.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{svdetect_refs}

\end{document}
```

Relevant citations from the .bib file:

```
@article{alkan2011sv,
      title={Genome structural variation discovery and genotyping},
      author={Alkan, Can and Coe, Bradley P and Eichler, Evan E},
      journal={Nature Reviews Genetics},
      volume={12},
      number={5},
      pages={363--376},
      year={2011},
      publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
    }

@article{rausch2012delly,
      title={DELLY: structural variant discovery by integrated paired-end and split-read analysis},
      author={Rausch, Tobias and Zichner, Thomas and Schlattl, Andreas and St{\"u}tz, Adrian M and Benes, Vladimir and Korbel, Jan O},
      journal={Bioinformatics},
      volume={28},
      number={18},
      pages={i333--i339},
      year={2012},
      publisher={Oxford Univ Press}
    }

@article{Layer2014lumpy,
      doi = {10.1186/gb-2014-15-6-r84},
      url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/gb-2014-15-6-r84},
      year  = {2014},
      publisher = {Springer Science $\mathplus$ Business Media},
      volume = {15},
      number = {6},
      pages = {R84},
      author = {Ryan M Layer and Colby Chiang and Aaron R Quinlan and Ira M Hall},
      title = {{LUMPY}: a probabilistic framework for structural variant discovery},
      journal = {Genome Biol}
    }
```

Comment: Just a side note: Wouldn't be '[6]-[8]' be better to avoid confusion with footnote superscripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After loading [`cite`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cite), update the `\citedash` to `--` (the default is `]--[`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{svdetect_refs.bib}
@article{alkan2011sv,
      title={Genome structural variation discovery and genotyping},
      author={Alkan, Can and Coe, Bradley P and Eichler, Evan E},
      journal={Nature Reviews Genetics},
      volume={12},
      number={5},
      pages={363--376},
      year={2011},
      publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
    }

@article{rausch2012delly,
      title={DELLY: structural variant discovery by integrated paired-end and split-read analysis},
      author={Rausch, Tobias and Zichner, Thomas and Schlattl, Andreas and St{\"u}tz, Adrian M and Benes, Vladimir and Korbel, Jan O},
      journal={Bioinformatics},
      volume={28},
      number={18},
      pages={i333--i339},
      year={2012},
      publisher={Oxford Univ Press}
    }

@article{Layer2014lumpy,
      doi = {10.1186/gb-2014-15-6-r84},
      url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/gb-2014-15-6-r84},
      year  = {2014},
      publisher = {Springer Science $\mathplus$ Business Media},
      volume = {15},
      number = {6},
      pages = {R84},
      author = {Ryan M Layer and Colby Chiang and Aaron R Quinlan and Ira M Hall},
      title = {{LUMPY}: a probabilistic framework for structural variant discovery},
      journal = {Genome Biol}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}
\renewcommand{\citedash}{--}% Default is ]--[
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Several tools rely on this identification of discordant read pairs to detect SV~\cite{alkan2011sv,rausch2012delly,Layer2014lumpy}.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{svdetect_refs}

\end{document}
```

For a `compress`ed output resembling `[X]-[Y]` (rather than the default `X]-[Y`), you can patch `\@cite@n` using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@cite@n}% <cmd>
  {\let\@celt\@compress@cite\@cite@list\@h@ld}% <search>
  {\citeleft\let\@celt\@compress@cite\@cite@list\@h@ld\citeright}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

The above patch inserts `\citeleft` (default is `[`) and `\citeright` (default is `]`) in the appropriate location.

[image]